# Compiling python3 C extensions

Tags: c, python-3.x, setuptools, python-extensions

I wrote the following code for my CPython extension :

```
#include <Python.h>
static PyObject *greeting(PyObject* self)
{
        return Py_BuildValue("s" , "Hello python modules!!!");
}

static char *my_docstring = "This is a sample docstring";

static PyMethodDef greeting_funcs[] = {
    {"greeting" , (PyCFunction)greeting , METH_NOARGS , my_docstring} , {NULL}
};

void initModule(void){
    Py_InitModule3("greeting" , greeting_funcs , "Module example!!!");
}
```

And when I execute the following in IPython3 shell

```
from setuptools import setup , Extension
modules = [Extension('mod', sources=["/home/spm/python_module/mod.c"])] 
setup(ext_modules=modules)
```

I get the error :

```
SystemExit: usage: ipython3 [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts]
or: ipython3 --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: ipython3 --help-commands
or: ipython3 cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `mod.c` won't compile. `Py_InitModule3` is removed in Python 3; you have to create a [`PyModuleDef`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModuleDef) struct and add an init function named `PyInit_{library name}` that passes the `PyModuleDef` reference 
to [`PyModule_Create`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_Create) to initialize the module:

```
#include <Python.h>
#define MY_DOCSTRING "This is a sample docstring"

static PyObject *greeting(PyObject* self)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("s" , "Hello python modules!!!");
}

static PyMethodDef greeting_funcs[] = {
    {"greeting" , (PyCFunction)greeting , METH_NOARGS , MY_DOCSTRING} , {NULL}
};


// python module definition
static struct PyModuleDef greetingModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "greeting", "Module example!!!", -1, greeting_funcs
};

// register module namespace
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_mod(void)
{
    PyObject *module;

    module = PyModule_Create(&greetingModule);
    if (module == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return module;
}
```

> And when I execute the following in IPython3 shell I get the error

This code is usually not invoked from IPython. It is put in a script named `setup.py` and then executed from terminal, supplying the tasks the `setup` function should invoke, e.g.

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

to build the extension module and place it into current directory.

Of course, you can mimic this in IPython too:

```
In [1]: import sys                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [2]: sys.argv.extend(["build_ext", "--inplace"])                                                                                                                                                                

In [3]: from setuptools import setup, Extension                                                                                                                                                                    

In [4]: modules = [Extension('mod', sources=["mod.c"])]                                                                                                                                                            

In [5]: setup(ext_modules=modules)                                                                                                                                                                                 
running build_ext
...

In [6]: sys.argv = sys.argv[:1]
```

However, a better solution is to write the setup code into the `setup.py` script. You can then execute it in IPython via the `%run` magic:

```
In [1]: %run setup.py build_ext --inplace                                                                                                                                                                          
running build_ext
building 'mod' extension
...
```